# Troubles with ddev + elasticsearch latest version

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, file-permissions, ddev

I'm facing some trouble when trying to start my ES containers on DDEV.

I've download the [official dockerfile from drud repository](https://github.com/drud/ddev-contrib/blob/master/docker-compose-services/elasticsearch/docker-compose.elasticsearch.yaml) and made some changes (Version,max nodes,etc) as you can see:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: ddev-${DDEV_SITENAME}-elasticsearch
    hostname: ${DDEV_SITENAME}-elasticsearch
    image: elasticsearch:6.8.0
    ports:
      - "9200"
      - "9300"
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=$DDEV_HOSTNAME
      - HTTP_EXPOSE=9200
      - node.max_local_storage_nodes=20
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    labels:
      com.ddev.site-name: ${DDEV_SITENAME}
      com.ddev.approot: $DDEV_APPROOT
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - ".:/mnt/ddev_config"
  web:
    links:
      - elasticsearch:elasticsearch

volumes:
  elasticsearch:
    name: "${DDEV_SITENAME}-elasticsearch"
```

so, when I run ddev start the container is not starting since I've migrated from 5.6 to 6.8.0

**Output**

> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was
>   deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future
>   release. OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: UseAVX=2 is not supported
>   on this CPU, setting it to UseAVX=1 [2020-03-04T17:32:31,770][WARN
>   ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [unknown] uncaught
>   exception in thread [main]
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to create node environment    at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:163)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:150)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124)
>   ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90)
>   ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:116)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:93)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0] Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to create node environment    at
>   org.elasticsearch.node.Node.(Node.java:299)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.node.Node.(Node.java:266)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.(Bootstrap.java:212)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:212)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:333)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]  ... 6 more Caused by:
>   java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException:
>   /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/1     at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:389)
>   ~[?:?]    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:692) ~[?:?]
>     at java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:799)
>   ~[?:?]    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:785)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.lambda$new$0(NodeEnvironment.java:273)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment$NodeLock.(NodeEnvironment.java:206)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.(NodeEnvironment.java:270)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.node.Node.(Node.java:296)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.node.Node.(Node.java:266)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.(Bootstrap.java:212)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:212)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:333)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]

**BTW, i'm using the docker compose version 3.6 because ddev latest version force you to use it**

Comment: First, this is not a Dockerfile. It's a docker-compose snippet used to add on custom services to DDEV-Local. And the docker-compose version is not 3.6, that's the compose file version. I know all the different versions are confusing. But here's the info on compose file versions: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/ - And A Dockerfile is used to build a docker image (completely different topic), see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Comment: You could also start with an explanation of why you need to use elasticsearch 6.8.

Comment: I would start by deleting the docker volume that this creates, probably named "ddev-<projectname>_elasticsearch". `docker volume ls | grep elasticsearch` and use `docker volume rm <name>` to delete it.

Comment: @rfay i'm integrating drupal with ES and i know the main difference, that was just a typo meanwhile i was writing the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are getting this error

```
.8.0.jar:6.8.0] ... 6 more Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/1 at
```

This means that you have some permission issues, check the permissions of the files

```
    - elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - ".:/mnt/ddev_config"
```

maybe you need to recreate or migrate the data also